# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' | i can't get the output filtered to only text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

job_title = []
company_name = []
location_name = []
job_skill = []
links = []
salary = []

result = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=web+development&l=&from=searchOnHP")
source = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

job_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"class", "jcs-JobTitle"})
company_names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "companyName"})
location_names = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "companyLocation"})
job_skills = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "job-snippet"})


for i in range(len(job_titles)):
    job_title.append(job_titles[i].text.strip())
    links.append("https://www.indeed.com" + job_titles[i].attrs["href"])
    company_name.append(company_names[i].text.strip())
    location_name.append(location_names[i].text.strip())
    job_skill.append(job_skills[i].text.strip())

for link in links:
    result = requests.get(link)
    source = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    salaries = soup.find("span", {"class": "icl-u-xs-mr--xs attribute_snippet"})
    salary.append(salaries.text)


my_file = [job_title, company_name, location_name, job_skill, salary]
exported = zip_longest(*my_file)
with open("/Users/Rich/Desktop/testing/indeed.csv", "w") as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(["Job titles", "Company names", "Location names", "Job skills", "salaries"])
    writer.writerows(exported)
```

i was scraping this website to get the job titles, company names, location names, job skills, and the salaries by scraping every page of them and it works when i print the commend:
salaries = soup.find("span", {"class": "icl-u-xs-mr--xs attribute_snippet"})
but when i try to append only the text from it i get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
please help me to get this fixed and it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is that there is not always a salary, so you have to handle this e.g. with an `if condition` and you could also avoid all these list.

```
salary.text if salary else None
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=web+development&l=&from=searchOnHP")
source = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

data = []
for e in soup.select('ul.jobsearch-ResultsList .slider_item'):
    salary = e.find("div",{"class": "salary-snippet-container"})
    data.append({
        'title': e.find("a", {"class", "jcs-JobTitle"}).get_text(strip=True),
        'company': e.find("span", {"class": "companyName"}).get_text(strip=True),
        'location': e.find("div", {"class": "companyLocation"}).get_text(strip=True),
        'skills': e.find("div", {"class": "job-snippet"}).get_text(strip=True),
        'salary': salary.text if salary else None
    })

with open('indeed.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = data[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```